# Test passing when it shouldn't

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-security, mockito

Authentication method:

```java
 @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signIn(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) {
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    loginDto.getEmail(), loginDto.getPassword()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("User signed-in successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Invalid credentials", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
```

Test:

```java
@Test
    void shouldLogin() throws Exception {
        LoginDto loginDto = new LoginDto("admin", "ye2esyes");
        String expectedMessage = "User signed-in successfully!";
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post("/auth/login")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginDto))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(expectedMessage));
    }
```

Those are wrong credentials but the test is still passing.
When i try to login using postman i actually get 401 with "Invalid credentials" But when i test with Mockmvc it's always passing.
I'm using Spring Security

Comment: What does me creating a new LoginDto has to do with the user being valid?

Comment: Use a debugger, go through the code step by step. See where the code doesn't behave as you expect, then try to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock `authenticationManager.authenticate` to throw BadCredentialsException to make it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the Authentication Manager and that can be done as below code snippet:

```
Mockito.doThrow(BadCredentialsException.class)
    .when(authenticationManager.authenticate(new 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDto.getEmail(), loginDto.getPassword())));
```

This should work fine !!

Comment: The above can be put into @Before block method if you wish to do the same operation for various test methods. OR it can also be part of your test block method. Anyways you like it, you can use it.

Comment: This code won't work because the instance of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` in the mock & the real instance of invocation don't match. And do not use `any()` (if you intend to change your answer to use it) because it's very bad & cannot verify anything, instead using ArgumentCaptor to ensure the passed arguments (e.g. email & password) match with what you prepare in test.

Answer (score 0):

It just turned out that I'm dumb and I forgot that I'm mocking the beans so there isn't actually a connection to the database.
I just ended up moving the authentication code to UserService class inside an authenticate() method that returns a boolean, then I stubbed the method and tested the controller and everything is working fine.
My test now:

```
@Test
    void shouldReturnUnauthorized() throws  Exception{
        final LoginDto validLoginDto = new LoginDto("admin", "yesyesyes");
        final String expectedMessage = "Invalid credentials";

        Mockito.when(userService.authenticate(validLoginDto)).thenReturn(false);

        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post("/auth/login")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(validLoginDto))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())
                .andExpect(content().string(expectedMessage));
    }
```

Comment: Although it works, but you mock useService which is not in your logic of code, it makes your test isn't isolation. This is not good, because if others changed code other codes, e.g. authenticationManager.authenticate, and it will lead to your test failed, but the reason of failure isn't yours. Then the test case which is testing for authenticationManager.authenticate should be failed instead. Making test cases isolation is very important.